# Use Perl Rename command to remove spaces before file extension (Linux)

Tags: linux, file, perl, rename

I am looking to be able to remove blank spaces from beginning and end of folder and filenames.  I am looking for these commands to be created using the Perl Rename command in Linux for Debian based systems.

I have a command that can remove the spaces from the beginning and the end of names but it removes the spaces from the end of the extension instead of the end of the filename itself before the extension, which is what I am looking to achieve.

File extensions always seem to throw me off, when it comes to things like the Rename command and with Regular Expressions in general, always cause me trouble :)

Here is the command that removes spaces from beginning and end of the extension

```
rename 's/^\s+|\s+$//g' *
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

A little question here is of what you consider an "*extension*" -- while `.txt` seems clear, what with `.tar.gz` or with having other periods in a filename (like `name.07.21.2023.v2.tar.gz`).

I'd guess that whitespace before *any* period is useless so a basic approach could be to strip all such. One way to do that

```
's/^\s+|\s+(?=\.)|\s+$//g'
```

That `(?=\.)` is a [positive lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind), asserting that there is a period right ahead but not consuming it.  Or, use two passes with a simple pattern to capture and put back the `.`

```
's/^\s+|\s+$//g; s/\s+(\.)/$1/g'
```

Comment: Same as my comment above, Thank you for your help I really appreaciate it.  Was not aware of "lookahead" and also I was not aware that you could run more than one command this way, I have used this in Bash but didn't know you could achieve this within Rename command itself, very good to know.  I had thought about things like version numbers in filenames and stuff like that but I forgot about items like tar.bz but great point that a space before any period wouldn't be desired, I like that.

Comment: @advice2020 "Lookarounds," as they call them in general, can be very useful but watch out as their logic and operation can be rather subtle and tricky. The rename program written in Perl (there is another, compiled, command with the same name), often installed as `prename`, can use any valid Perl code in the first argument. It manipulates the variable `$_` (default in Perl for many things) which has the filename, in any legit way. Try this: Make a file with a silly name, say, `a_tt_f.txt` and then run `rename '@w = split /_/; $_ = join ".", @w' a_tt_f_txt`. It changes all `_` to `.` [...]

Comment: @advice2020 [cont'd] One can of course do that with a simple `'s/_/./g'` instead -- I'm only saying that any legitimate Perl code works there, where `$_` has the filename. But keep in mind: **any valid Perl code goes**. In the example in my comment above, add `system("ls -l");` for instance -- it'll run `ls -l` on all files in the directory. So careful with what Perl commands you use there! Could do damage like with any program you write.

Comment: @advice2020 I find this [manpage for it](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html) -- It says: "_The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the $\_ string in Perl for at least some of the filenames specified._" Etc. (But instead of the "_$\_ string in Perl_" it should say "_The string in the $\_ variable in Perl_")

Answer (score 2):

I shall define "the extension" to be: `\.[^.]+$`

With a capture group:

```
rename 's/^\s+//; s/\s+(\.[^.]+$)/$1/' *
```

With a lookahead:

```
rename 's/^\s+//; s/\s+(?=\.[^.]+$)//' *
```

Comment: You might also want a rule to trim whitespace at the end if there is no extension (eg. `s/^\s*([^.]+)\s*$/$1/`)

Comment: handling multi-level extensions will be trickier (eg. `base.name.tar.gz.uu`)

Comment: Thank you again for your help I really appreaciate it.  Was not aware of "lookahead" and also I was not aware that you could run more than one command this way, I have used this in Bash but didn't know you could achieve this within Rename command itself, very good to know.  I had thought about things like version numbers in filenames and stuff like that but I forgot about items like tar.bz